# Scrolling in a TextView Inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a listview which has a scrollbar. Inside the listview each item/row has 2 textviews of which the third textview is scrollable.

i am setting the data to the listview using an Array Adapter.

But i am not able to scroll the textview.

My listview looks like:-

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="480dip" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_height="60dip"  android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000000"/>
```

My xml which i am using to inflate the view is

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rowlayout_row2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="0dip" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5C5C5C" android:text="Commenmts "
        android:textSize="12dip" android:typeface="sans" android:paddingTop="3dip"
        android:paddingLeft="3dip" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/review_data_id" android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip" android:gravity="left" android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview1" android:textColor="#5C5C5C"
        android:textSize="12dip" android:typeface="sans" android:paddingTop="3dip"
        android:paddingLeft="3dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried to make it fosuble but that did not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put one scrollable container into another scrollable container as it will not work. You have an UI design flaw if you encounter such a problem which means that you should rethink your UI.